# React/Express Reads Locally but Cannot Be Found in Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I deployed my React/Express application to Heroku after checking that it ran locally with no issues. However, upon deployment to Heroku, the application is no longer working. I receive a 404 error and do not understand why the app is not connecting.

I looked through my code to see if I could find any obvious typos or anything like that. I've searched through questions on here but couldn't find anything similar to my problem.

The tree looks like this:

```
express-backend
|__client
|   |__node_modules
|   |__src
|   |   |_App.js
|   |   |_index.js
|   |   |_{other components)
|   |__package-lock.json
|   |__package.json
|   |__README.md
|
|__node_modules
|__index.js
|__package-lock.json
|__package.json
```

Snippet from my express package.json folder:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));


const recipes = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'PBJ',
        url:'https://www.hormelfoods.com/wp-content/uploads/Newsroom_20170724_SKIPPY-Peanut-Butter-and-Jelly-Sandwich.jpg',
        ingredients: [null, null],
        directions: [null, null]
    }, 
]

app.get('/api/recipes', (req, res) =>
    res.send(recipes)
);

...
//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on Port ${port}`));
```

My client Component that should render on the home page, which is supposed to loop through recipes and create a recipe tile for each one.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Tile from './tile';
import './App.css';

class RecipeBook extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            recipes: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/recipes')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(recipes => this.setState({ recipes: recipes }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="wrapper">
                {this.state.recipes.map((recipe) => {
                    return <Tile recipe={recipe} key={recipe.id} />
                })}

                <Link to="./form.js">
                    <button className="Recipe-Card Tiny-Card">

                        <h1>+</h1>

                        <h2 className="Recipe-Label">ADD NEW RECIPE</h2>

                    </button>
                </Link>
            </div>        
        )
    }
}



export default RecipeBook;
```

When I open the app locally, it works fine. When I open the deployed app on Heroku, I receive a 404 Not Found error.

General Headers:

```
Request URL: https://deployed-recipe-book.herokuapp.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 52.21.245.216:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 00:42:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

The error message says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: you need to explain the steps that you did to push to heroku.

Comment: git add ., git push heroku master

Comment: You need to run the build process and then copy only the `built` files to the heroku server.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion here but how do I copy those built files to the server after the build process?

Comment: There are few ways, one is if you commit your built files(usually in `dist` folder) to your github, then you can modify your express script static file servering path to the `dist` folder. If not, then you have to push only the files from dist folder to heroku and it would automatically serve the files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run client and server separately, the client folder is not running at all that's why you are get 404.